# How to transform following data table in another structure

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, min

I've the following data table:

```
year, month,  customer, agent 
2013,  1,     abc,      yyyy 
2013,  2,     abc,      yyyy 
2013,  3,     abc,      zzzz 
2013,  4,     abc,      xxxx 
... 
2013,  12,    abc,      xxxx
```

I need to transform this table in a structure like

```
year, from, to, customer, agent
2013, 1,    2   abc,      yyyy
2013, 3,    3   abc,      zzzz
2013, 4,    12  abc,      xxxx
```

So i've tried using MAX and MIN function to identify MIN and MAX month for customer and agent.. but it don't work.

Can you help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: I *do* wonder what you tried!

Comment: i forgot to "group by " !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.year, 
       MIN(A.month) `from`,
       MAX(A.month) `to`, 
       A.customer, 
       A.agent
FROM tableA A
GROUP BY A.year,
         A.customer, 
         A.agent
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84329/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| YEAR | FROM | TO | CUSTOMER | AGENT |
|------|------|----|----------|-------|
| 2013 |    4 | 12 |      abc |  xxxx |
| 2013 |    1 |  2 |      abc |  yyyy |
| 2013 |    3 |  3 |      abc |  zzzz |
```